# What does this piece of code do and what does each of the symbols used mean? The language used is C and I am just a beginner to coding

Tags: c, unsigned, conditional-operator

Came across a code of which I couldn't understand what these two lines are doing. Can't even get the syntax. Please specify what type of functionalities have been used like for eg I am guessing that there has been a use of conditional operators in the first line.

```
unsigned long long base_size = b >= 2 ? (b-2)/2:0;
printf("%llu\n",(base_size*(base_size+1))/2);
```

Comment: It's the conditional operator

Comment: [Ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: Get a book about the C language. Then look up the ?: operator, also called ternary operator, or conditional operator. Next look up the printf standard library function and its format strings.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [operator priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is c, the first line is effectively

```
unsigned long long base_size = ( b >= 2 ? (b-2)/2:0 );
```

Now, the expression inside `( )` uses a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) or Conditional operator.

As per the `C11` standard, chapter 6.5.15, the syntax is

```
conditional-expression:
                    logical-OR-expression
                    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

and the semantics is [follow my emphasis]

> **The first operand is evaluated;** there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). **The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second
>   or third operand (whichever is evaluated)** converted to the type described below<sup>NOTE</sup>.
>
> <sup>NOTE: A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.</sup>

So, following that, your case,

```
b >= 2 ? (b-2)/2:0
```

first, the first expression, `b >= 2` is evaluated. if `b` has value greater than or equal to `2`, it returns `1`, otherwise, `0`.

- if it evaluates to `1`, the second operand, `(b-2)/2` is executed and the final result of the conditional operator is the value of the expression.
- similarly, it evaluates to `0`, the third operand `0` is returned as the result of the conditional operator.

Finally, the return value of the ternary operator is used to initialize the `unsigned long long base_size` variable.

About the second line, `printf()` is a standard C library function, prototyped in `stdio.h`. You can find more on this [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: @iharob Thank you. BTW Updated my answer. Please review it. :-)

Comment: @iharob Now that's a nice thing to hear from an active SO member. Thanks and cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

What is used here is the conditional operator ( Also called ternary operator because it uses 3 expressions) The format of the conditional operator is

```
expression1 ? expression2 : expression3.
```

Now let me explain this.

If `expression1` evaluates to true, then the value of the whole expression is the value of `expression2`, otherwise, the value of the whole expression is `expression3`.

Now take this simple example

```
result = marks >= 50 ? 'P' : 'F' ;
```

`result` will have the value `'P'` if the expression `marks >= 50` evaluates to true, otherwise, `result` will get `'F'`.

Now let us move on to your case

```
unsigned long long base_size = b >= 2 ? (b-2)/2:0; 
printf("%llu\n",(base_size*(base_size+1))/2);
```

It checks if `b >= 2`, if it is, then assigns `base_size` the value `(b-2)/2` else it assigns `base_size` the value 0.

It is also the equivalent of

```
if( b >= 2 )
   base_size = ( b - 2 ) / 2;
else
   base_size = 0;
```

Now, just in case you don't know

```
printf("%llu\n",(base_size*(base_size+1))/2);
```

What this does is outputs the value of `base_size * ( base_size + 1 ) / 2` onto your output screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the ternary operator

```
x = condition ? value : another_value;
```

means

```
if (condition)
    x = value;
else
    x = another_value;
```

it's evident that `value` and `another_value` should have the same type as `x` and that `condition` must be an expression which can evaluate to a truth value.

The code you posted though doesn't look good because it's hard to read, it would be way better this way

```
unsigned long long base_size;

base_size = (b >= 2) ? (b - 2) / 2 : 0;
printf("%llu\n", (base_size * (base_size + 1)) / 2);
```

and this would be equivalent to

```
if (b >= 2)
    printf("%llu\n", (((b - 2) / 2) * (((b - 2) / 2) + 1)) / 2);
else
    printf("0\n");
```